# Visual Studio 2019 or Dev.Azure.com - How can I get a list of the code that I or another user has committed, by date?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 or Dev.Azure.com - How can I get a list of the code that I or another user has committed, by date

When I use the VS2019 Git Branch History I cannot see how to:

1. Filter by user (search sort of works, matching users and titles to user name)
2. Sort by date (it is in an "interesting"* order)

*interesting meaning that I have no clue

Comment: Do you mean commits made by a specific user? Checked in is a TFS term

Comment: Yes. commits. I am so old that I mean that the punch cards were turned in. Should I edit?

Comment: I know you can view the list of commits but not the code by git log --all --oneline --author="username" but you'd probably have better luck looking at the remote repo website for the code and filter.